# How to turn a for loop using table models into a lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, tablemodel

Is there any way to turn this Loop into a Lambda Expression?
I want to get certain rows out of the column and fill a list with them by checking if the list value is empty or 'called'.

I am using c#.

```
private List<String> GetCurrentListRows(GridTableModel modl, int col)
    {
        List<String> list = new List<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < modl.RowCount+1; i++)
        {
            var listVal = modl.Model[i, col].Text;
            if (listVal != "" && listVal != "Called")
            {
                list.Add(modl.Model[i, 9].Text);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you brief us what you are doing with list.Add(modl.Model[i, 9].Text);

Comment: what is the datatype of modl.Model?

Comment: Thank you for your quick Responses! modl is the tablemodel from a grid. With list.Add(modl.Model[i, 9].Text); I want to create a list with the rows in the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private List<String> GetCurrentListRows(GridTableModel modl, int col)
{
    List<String> list = Enumerable
        .Range(0, modl.RowCount)
        .Where(i => modl[i, col].Text != "" && modl[i, col].Text != "Called")
        .Select(i => modl[i, 9].Text)
        .ToList(); 
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I had to add + 1 at List<String> list = Enumerable.Range(0, modl.RowCount + 1)...  because of the last element in that modl

Comment: Are you sure? modl[modl.RowCount, 0] should throw a IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: It doesn't and I've got the last missing list element with this

Answer (score 1):

Try this code below:

```
    private List<String> GetCurrentListRows(GridTableModel modl, int col)
    {
       return modl.Where(listVal => (!String.IsNullorEmpty(listVal.Text))
                .Where(listVal => listVal.Text != "Called").Select(modl.Text).ToList(); 

    }
```

Comment: Yeah, we don't know what the model is like. Just got to know what model the developer is using.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume modl.Model is SomeClass[][]...

```
private List<String> GetCurrentListRows(GridTableModel modl, int col)
{
    return modl.Model.Where(a => a[col].Text != "" && a[col].Text != "Called")
        .Select(a => a[9].Text)
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how GridTableModel is structured but i guess you can make your changes easily.

First you'll have to create an extension to flatten your 2d array.

```
   public static class ArrayLinq
    {
        public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Flatten(this string[,] map, int colcheck, int colvalue)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < map.GetLength(0); row++)
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(map[row, colcheck], map[row, colvalue]);
            }
        }
    }
```

the first param is to apply to your modl.Model, the second is the column to check and the last one is the column to pickup. I return a KeyValuePair since you need to item the column to check and the column(9) to pick as value. But you can change it as you wish

Then your function should change like this

```
private IList<string> GetCurrentListRows(GridTableModel modl, int col)
{
    return modl.Model.Flatten(col, 9)
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Key) && x.Key != "Called")
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .ToList();
}
```

It's a nice LINQ exercise of functional programming.